# Issue with basic create statements in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've used the psql module to create a new database using the following syntax:

```
CREATE DATABASE fish
```

I can open the database. However, when I try to create tables or columns it gives me a syntax error for the following message.

```
CREATE TABLE salmon;
```

this is the error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE species;
```

I've checked a lot of online postgreSQL resources and they haven't been of much help. To the best of my knowledge, I haven't messed up the syntax. Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify columns when you create your table, or at least the primary key.

Comment: Please read the [tutorial in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntax for empty table:

```
create table salmon();
```

You must create atleast one column in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE salmon ( column_name data_type ...........);
```

Postgres create table link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an empty table - it must have at least one column. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE salmon (name VARCHAR(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `psql` is not a module. Please read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html
2. you odn't open a database - you connect to it.

> Establishes a new connection to a PostgreSQL server

3. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

> { column_name | ( expression ) }

Either column list (`create table a (a int);`) or expression (`create table b as select now() time_column`) is obligatory part.